# Query data from Shopify using GraphQL into ios app. Xcode - SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, graphql, shopify

Im trying to receive data from Shopify using GraphQL. I am able to fetch data by giving the product ID and receiving the data in Storefront.Product form, however I need it to be in Storefront.ProductEdge form.

Heres my code:

```
final class ClientQuery {
    static func queryForProduct(id: String) -> Storefront.QueryRootQuery {
    let id = GraphQL.ID(rawValue: id)
    return Storefront.buildQuery { $0
        .node(id: id) { $0
            .onProduct() { $0
                .id()
                .title()
                .variants(first: 1){ $0
                    .edges() { $0
                        .node(){ $0
                            .availableForSale()
                            .priceV2(){ $0
                                .amount()
                            }
                        }
                    }
              }
                .description()
                .images( first: 1){ $0
                    .fragmentForStandardProductImage()

                }
            }
        }
    }
}//end of final class
```

.

```
final class Client{

@discardableResult
func fetchProduct(id: String, completion: @escaping (Storefront.Product?) -> Void) -> Task {
    let query = ClientQuery.queryForProduct(id: id)

     let task  = self.client.queryGraphWith(query) { (query, error) in
         error.debugPrint()

        if let product = query?.node as? Storefront.Product? {
        completion (product)
        }
        else {
        print("Failed to fetch Product: \(String(describing: error))")
        completion (nil)
            }
        }
     task.resume()
     return task
   }
  }
 }//end of final class
```

.

```
viewDidLoad(){
            Client.shared.fetchProduct(id: sku) { Product1 in
               guard let Product1 = Product1 else {
                   print("Failed to fetch Product")
                   return
             }    
  }
```

This code works and I am able to get certain values of product, such as title and image.
However I want to get the data as Type `Storefront.ProductEdge` instead of `Storefront.Product`, to make displaying data better.
But when I change `fetchProduct` to:

```
   @discardableResult
func fetchProduct(id: String, completion: @escaping (Storefront.ProductEdge?) -> Void) -> Task {
    let query = ClientQuery.queryForProduct(id: id)

     let task  = self.client.queryGraphWith(query) { (query, error) in
         error.debugPrint()

        if let product = query?.node as? Storefront.ProductEdge? {
        completion (product)
        }
        else {
        print("Failed to fetch Product: \(String(describing: error))")
        completion (nil)
            }
        }
     task.resume()
     return task
}
```

.

Then I get `"Failed to fetch Product: nil"` and `"Failed to fetch Product"`

What is going on? And how can I call the product data out as Storefront.ProductEdge type?

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers